# Css calc() behavior in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, css-calc

My purpose is to put inner `div` in the middle of container.

The example in 
[fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/tuwd3tqg/)

The main problem is that inner div is shifted right in IE (Firefox and Chrome shows it fine) because of using css `calc()` rule.  If I uncomment constant width in example above `width: 156px`, it works.

But it doesn't with `calc()`. Is there any way to fix it for IE?

P.S. as I know IE8 and lower doesn't support `calc()`, I was trying it in IE9.

Comment: It would help if we knew what this was *supposed9 to look like.

Comment: @Paulie_D, as I wrote above, other browsers displays it correctly (just try to open this fiddle in Chrome). The main target is to display text in p tag right aligned horizontally and in the middle vertically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this new fiddle, there where a couple of errors in your CSS. Here ya go:

http://jsfiddle.net/tuwd3tqg/1/

---

First off though, you where using `position: absolute`, and I don't know why. Second, you where using `top` and `right`, for those you must use `position: relative`. Third you where using `right`, which I changed to `margin-right`, and the items have to be `float: right` to use `right`.

---

**EDIT**

If you would like text aligned in the center add the following property to your wrapper `text-align: center`. Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tuwd3tqg/2/

Comment: Thanks, it definitely helps! I just was at a loss because Chrome and Firefox handles that another (correct as I guess) way, so I consideredthe problem is in calc()

Answer (score 0):

give your class

```
.column {
   text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: A little explanation of your code would be more helpful.

Comment: @Sersi, I'm afraid it doesn't work (have just tried it in fiddle in IE)